# Missing Resource Group Field in Azure DevOps Starter Wizard

Tags: azure

The DevOps Starter wizard in Azure portal for creating a new AKS cluster seems to be missing Resource group field. Is this normal or is there another way to specify it?[Azure-DevOpsStarter-Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiuNN.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal and there is no resource group field.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did see a Resource Group field under Additional settings under the Kubernetes Service section. Is that applicable to the entire DevOps starter or just the Kubernetes cluster?